# Warning(unlink) Warning: session_start() Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: warnings

For website truelove4hope.org. Only the homepage has this issue. And only for Firefox on my computer. Chrome works just fine.

Warning: unlink(/home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/uploads/fw-backup/fw-backup-2018_11_22-03_03_06-2.0.27.zip): No such file or directory in /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions/backups/includes/module/schedule/class--fw-ext-backups-module-schedule.php on line 332

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions/backups/includes/module/schedule/class--fw-ext-backups-module-schedule.php:332) in /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/includes/hooks.php on line 258

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions/backups/includes/module/schedule/class--fw-ext-backups-module-schedule.php:332) in /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/includes/hooks.php on line 258

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-content/plugins/unyson/framework/extensions/backups/includes/module/schedule/class--fw-ext-backups-module-schedule.php:332) in /home2/wondesk2/public_html/truelove4hope/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219

Thanx!

Comment: Put the @ symbol before unlink (to suppress PHP's error messages - you have your own error notifications anyway) or do a file_exists() test before unlink()ing.

Comment: add code your wp-config-php file

Comment: ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);